# AutoMapper Mapping a collection of strings to a property of a collection inside another collection

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

How to mapping IdContributors (collection of strings) to a collection (Contributors), inside a collection TAction, with a property (ContributorId) of string, using LINQ and AutoMapper ?

```cs
public ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ActionViewModel, TAction>();
                //.ForMember(d => d.Contributors, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => ids = a.IdContributors.Select(x => { })));

        }
```

**Models**

**Model TAction**

```cs
public class TAction
    {
        public Guid Id {get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TActionContributor> Contributors { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
public class TActionContributor
    {
        public Guid TActionId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("TActionId")] 
        public TAction Action { get; set; }
        
        public string ContributorId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("ContributorId")] 
        public ApplicationUser Contributor { get; set; }
    }
```

**ActionViewModel**

```cs
public class ActionViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<string> IdContributors { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Try this : `ForMember(av=> av.IdContributors,r=> r.MapFrom(ta=> ta.Contributors.Select(c=>c.ContributorId ).ToArray())`

Comment: it's ActionViewModel to TAction, not the reverse.

Comment: You need to query for the contributors by yourself without using AutoMapper. Filter by action id and check if contributor id is in ids collections.

Comment: @Prolog doesn't make sense. It's a mapping from a model to other model. I know that is possible using IValueResolver but maybe has easiest way using linq.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two choices here, you'll choose the solution which better suits your needs:

---

#### 1) Select() in from MapFrom()

```cs
CreateMap<ActionViewModel, TAction>()
    .ForMember(
        destination => destination.Contributors,
        options => options.MapFrom((source, destination) =>
        {
            var contributors = source
                .IdContributors
                .Select(id => new TActionContributor
                {
                    Action = destination,
                    Contributor = new ApplicationUser
                    {
                        Id = id,
                    },
                    ContributorId = id,
                    TActionId = source.Id,
                })
                .ToList();

            contributors.ForEach(ac => ac.Contributor.Contributors = contributors);

            return contributors;
        }));
```

---

#### 2) Custom ValueResolver

This is the same as the first solution, maybe more readable if you want to keep your mapping profiles clean and move the custom logic away when possible.

```cs
public class TActionContributorValueResolver : IValueResolver<ActionViewModel, TAction, ICollection<TActionContributor>>
{
    public ICollection<TActionContributor> Resolve(
        ActionViewModel source,
        TAction destination,
        ICollection<TActionContributor> destMember,
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var contributors = source
            .IdContributors
            .Select(id => new TActionContributor
            {
                Action = destination,
                Contributor = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Id = id,
                },
                ContributorId = id,
                TActionId = source.Id,
            })
            .ToList();

        contributors.ForEach(ac => ac.Contributor.Contributors = contributors);

        return contributors;
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```cs
CreateMap<ActionViewModel, TAction>()
    .ForMember(
        destination => destination.Contributors,
        options => options.MapFrom<TActionContributorValueResolver>());
```

---

#### Final note:

```cs
contributors.ForEach(ac => ac.Contributor.Contributors = contributors);
```

Line above allows you to traverse endlessly from `TAction` through `TActionContributor` to `ApplicationUser` and the other way. If you don't need that feature, feel from to remove it and return the `contributors` list right away.